Is there a way to automate the use of sonarqube?
Currently I am working on a project that wants to integrate automated static analysis as a part of a pipeline. I simply want to just feed in a piece of code to sonarqube and have it output the results, all done with a single command to run a script.
Right now I am so close to full automation. I have a script that runs SonarQube in a docker container, handles the creation of analysis tokens, outputting results...etc. But the main issue I am facing is that I don't know how to automate the part where we need to connect to localhost 9000, change the password from admin to whatever we want, and then log in to my admin account. In order for my automation to work I need to go through this process manually on the SonarQube interface and I don't know how to integrate this step into my script so I don't need to go and manually log into an account every time. Does anyone have any idea on how to go about this?

Good evening,
just for my curiousity: Are you creating a fresh sonarqube instance per scan? If so, why? :)
If not, just use an authentication token? https://docs.sonarsource.com/
If yes, sounds like you want to do an oidc login with username/password, change the password and login again? Can't understand your flow fully right now.
To change your password by commandline / script, use the api:
curl -u admin:admin -X POST "http://localhost:9000/api/users/change_password?login=admin&previousPassword=admin&password=XXXXXXXXX"

Source, Documentation and Api-Documentation
Best regards

Hi! I am not creating a fresh sonarqube instance. I create one initially and then I just use that authentication token for all future scans. The thing is that still requires me to manually do an oidc login and I was wondering if there was a way to automate that part as well as this is all part of a automated pipeline where I am trying to minimize manual configuration.
Thank you I think that script command might work! I'll give it a try. This is my first time writing scripts so it's been a learning curve haha
